# VBA - Is there a way to code an all-purpose select-all and copy function for getting data from most Windows applications?

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard

I run several Windows applications (not always related to each other) from time to time and press Control-A to select all, Control-C to copy, and then I paste to an Excel file. I don't have access to the data source, so I can't create a link. I looked into screenshotting and doing OCR, but I ran a quick test with OneNote and it failed to convert to text (probably because of the strange font and colors). I'm thinking now of sending keys to the application.

My question is if there is a way to assign an object to an open application and then send control-A, control-C to it to gather the data values via clipboard.

I know enough VBA to mess around with the clipboard, but I don't know how to point to an open (third-party) application and I do not know how to send keys. Any links or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `AppActivate` and `SendKeys` should be all you need...

Comment: That seems to be simple enough. That answers my question. Thanks.